# Pandas - Trying to assign values to dataframe based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to assign a value to a column based on a selection of multiple criteria.
I'm trying to create the following logic:

if field1 is null and field2 is null then assign fieldTemp to 0.

I have no problem applying the logic based on one column:

```
df.loc[df['field1'].isnull(), 'fieldTemp'] = 0
```

It gets difficult once I try and test for 'field2' is null with and and operator.
Anybody know if there is a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need two conditions

```
df.loc[df['field1'].isnull() & df['field3'].isnull(), 'fieldTemp'] = 0
```